# Python: Three couples crossing a river

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbee to python and computing. This is the problem that I want to implement by using Python:Three couples want to cross a river, from east to west. A boat found there can take only two persons. How to cross the river if a wife can't stay with other men without her husband?

First I created all the possible states.

```
def genStates():
    """
    A function to generate all the possible states.
    Input: None
    Output: all the possible states

    """

    states = []
    side = ("E","W")

    for a in side:
        for b in side:
            for c in side:
                for d in side:
                    for e in side:
                        for f in side:
                            z = a+b+c+d+e+f
                            states.append(z)
    return states
```

Then I created a graph to put legal states and their possible moves.

```
def genGraph(S):
    """
    A function to generate a graph that contains all the legal states and their next possible states to move
    Input: All the possible states
    Output: A graph of all the legal states and their next possible states to move

    """

    G = []
    graph = {}
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if isLegal(S[i]) == True:
            G.append(S[i])

    for i in range(len(G)):
        result1 = nextStates(G[i], G)
        graph.update({G[i]: result1[1:]})  # add possible states to each legal states, put it in graph
    return graph
```

I created two functions that are used in genGraph.

```
def isLegal(S):
    """
    A function to check if a state is legal or not.
    Input: None
    Output: Return True if a state is legal, else return False.

    """

    if S[0] != S[1]:
        if S[1] == S[2] or S[1] == S[4]:
            return False
    elif S[2] != S[3]:
        if S[3] == S[0] or S[3] == S[4]:
            return False
    elif S[4] != S[5]:
        if S[5] == S[0] or S[5] == S[2]:
            return False

    return True
```

and

```
def nextStates(startnode, allstates):
    """
    A function to return a set of states that a state can move to.
    Input: A state and all the possible states
    Output: a set of states that a state can move to

    """

    possible = [startnode]
    count1 = startnode.count("E")
    count2 = startnode.count("W")
    for i in range(1, len(allstates)):
        if allstates[i].count("E") - count1 <= 2 and allstates[i].count("E") - count1 >= -2 and allstates[i].count(
                "W") - count2 <= 2 and allstates[i].count("W") - count2 >= -2:
            count = 0
            for j in range(0,len(startnode)):
                if allstates[i][j] == startnode[j]:
                    count += 1
            if count >= 4:  # Unlike MCGW problem, single unit's journey is unnecessary
                possible.append(allstates[i])
    return possible
```

and finally, I used a function from a python website to get the shortest path to implement this problem.

```
def genShortestPath(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    """
    A function to find the shortest path in a graph, from the start to the destination.
    Input: A graph of all the legal states and their states next possible states to move, the starting point and the destination
    Output: the shortest path of the graph

    """

    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not (start in graph):
        return None
    shortestPath = None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = genShortestPath(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortestPath or len(newpath) < len(shortestPath):
                    shortestPath = newpath
    return shortestPath
```

And finally, when I implement this problem, it can't find the shortest solution for some reasons. I printed out the graph, and next states functions to check if there's any problems for these, but it was working pretty well. What is the problem here? This is the implementing code:

```
def Solver():
    S = genStates()
    G = genGraph(S)
    s = "EEEEEE"  # source node
    d = "WWWWWW"  # destination node
    result = genShortestPath(G, s, d)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Really, it's all over the place. I'm having trouble reading your question.

Comment: Following up on connectyourcharger's comment, you can paste code right into your question, then select it and click on `{}` or press Ctrl+K to indent the whole thing so SO will treat it as code.

Comment: there are only 3 couples so there are 3W and 3E at most - why do you have states with more than that?

Comment: Patrick I'm not seeing where they do?

Comment: Victory: I'm seeing a lot of the following pattern in your code: `for i in range(len(sides)): side = sides[i]...` But Python allows you to simply write `for side in sides`, which is a lot more readable. If you do need an `i` / iteration variable, you can just write `for i, side in enumerate(sides)`, which saves you a line of code and will make people say "Hmm, yes, very pythonic."

Comment: A good way to solve a big problem like this is: create a system that allows you to solve the problem if there's only one wife and husband, then test it against two wives and husbands, then move up to three. Here's an example of how I refactored this code to support that with just a few changes: https://repl.it/repls/LightyellowBountifulGuiltware

Comment: Now that I can run this with only 1 wife and husband, it looks like the `nextStates` function is not working. That said, I am having a huge amount of trouble reading that function to figure out how it's trying to do its work. I would recommend starting over with either that function, or writing the entire script from the bottom up - this time, start with LENGTH = 2 and make sure your function can solve the puzzle with only one wife and one husband, because if it can't do that, it certainly won't be able to solve it with three.